# How to FIND (not FIX) text cut off in a cell in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am generating a Word Document programmatically.  It contains many tables with cells whose heights have to be defined “exactly”.  The cells are populated programmatically with details that are obtained from an external source.  If the details are too much for the cell the “exact” height of the cell will cause the text to be cut off.  When this happens I want to write some message to a log file to tell the user about it.  I know various ways to make the text fit, but my question is how do I determine programmatically that the text does not fit.

I have tried testing the Range property of the cell object and the Range property of the text being written to the cell, but they are essentially the same range.  I have tested the End properties of the ranges hoping that the position of the end of the text would be later than the end of the cell, but they are the same.  I have tested the Information(6) [constant wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage] property of the ranges after collapsing them to the end, but no difference.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there would be a straightforward way for that. What you can do is set row height to fit to content and see whether it has increased. (Don't do it in your main document, but copy to a temporary one)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Most likely this will require VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comments.  I have managed to solve the problem.

As mentioned, I am creating the Word document programmatically not manually.  To do so I am interacting with the various properties and methods of the Word Application object.  This can be done using Visual Basic but I happen to be using a different language.  I will try to describe the process of my solution in a language-independent way.

Step 1: Create an object (*cellobj*) to refer to the cell being examined. [ **Cell** method of a table object.]  This is a cell that has been merged from several cells, each of which started life with a row height set programmatically to some fixed height.  Text has been written programmatically to this cell.  The user interface of what I am writing allows the user to specify the fixed height(s) as well as the font and font size that will be used for the cell.  I also have no direct control of what text has been programmatically written into the cell.  An inappropriate mix will cause the text to be cut off according to the fixed height.

Step 2: Use the **Height** property (*cellobj*.**Height**) to get the height of the cell.  This is reported in points.

Step 3: Use the **Range** property to define a range object (*rangeobj*) associated with the cell. (*cellobj*.**Range**)

Step 4: Determine the start and end of the range. (*startval*=*rangeobj*.**Start** , *endval*=*rangeobj*.**End**). Note that the end of the range (of the cell) is the same as the start of the next cell.  A problem with this is that the supposed vertical distance of the “end” of the cell (measured from the top of the page) is actually the same as the vertical distance of the top of the next cell, which is the same vertical distance as the current cell.

Step 5: Determine the vertical distance (*vdist1*) that the top of the cell is from the top of the page. (*vdist1*=*rangeobj*.**Information(6)**  ).   As for step 2, this is reported in points.

Step 6: Set the start and end of the range to *endval*-1.  ( *rangeobj*.**Start**=*endval*-1 , *rangeobj*.**End**= *endval*-1).  Now the range extends to the end of the cell, not to the start of the next cell.

Step 7: Determine the vertical distance (*vdist2*) that the new top of the range (i.e. the bottom of the cell) is from the top of the page. (*vdist2*=*rangeobj*.**Information(6)**  ).

Step 8: Calculate the implied height of the cell. *vdist2- vdist1*. If this is greater than the height determined in step 2 it means that the text in the cell has been cut off.  I can now tell the user where in the (very long) document this problem occurs and provide some suggestions as what to do.

I was a bit worried in step 7 if the cell is split across a page.  The reference pages for vertical distance from the top of “the page” in steps 5 and 7 would then be different pages.  However, a fortunate side effect of setting a row height to be “exactly” some value is that the row is prevented from splitting across a page.

PS
The reason the heights of cells and rows need to be specified “exactly” is that similar tables are repeated on many consecutive pages. When the document is printed for publishing as a book, corresponding rows of the tables on facing pages need to line up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).